# Problema ao recuperar o id inserido

Tags: php, sql-server

Criei um cadastro com uns 58 dados.

A medida que fui criando, fui testando e os dados estavam entrando no BD, sendo que cada vez que uma inserção era feita, eu pego o `id` do último conjunto/grupo de dados inseridos.

Só que se eu "der um *refresh* na página" quando vou fazer um novo cadastro, os dados não são mais cadastrados no BD, é como se o `id` do último cadastro fosse perdido, pois eu coloquei um `echo` para mostrar o `id` criado e agora não vejo mais.

O erro que acontece é:

> Array ( [0] => Array (
>           [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14
>           [code] => -14 
>           [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to  sqlsrv_next_result.
>          [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to  sqlsrv_next_result. ) ) 1

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

```
$sqlProto = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[Protocolo] (titulo, $transicaoCentralCorresp) VALUES (?,?)";

$sqlProto = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[Protocolo] (titulo, $transicaoCentralCorresp) VALUES (?,?); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS last_id ";

$paramsProto = array($titulo, $transicaoCentralCorresp);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlProto, $paramsProto);

if($next_result){
   $item = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
   $uId = $item['last_id'];
   echo "Último id inserido ". $uId."<br>";
}else{
   die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
}
```

Comment: Dica: Existe por acaso trigger neste proceso? Isto pode influênciar no retorno, e confirme se para o retorno é utilizado o comando `@id_Transacao = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, que pega o ultimo `insert` da seleção principal, não de outra seção.

Comment: Mas você faz o `SELECT` antes para pegar o último ID inserido ? Só vejo `INSERT` em seu código. Mas você pode seguir a sugestão do KaduAmaral.

Answer (score 1):

Para casos em que é necessário o retorno do id gerado automaticamente, o *SQL Server* possui a cláusula ***OUTPUT***.

Na maioria dos casos é mais recomendado seu uso em comparação com ***SCOPE_IDENTITY()***.

Veja exemplo abaixo.

```
Tabela: produto
idproduto - int - autoincremento
descricao - varchar(40)
```

Ao executar o *insert*, o id já será retornado pela cláusula ***OUTPUT***:

```
INSERT INTO produto (descricao) 
OUTPUT inserted.idproduto 
VALUES ('armário');
```

Mais informações aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850422/3497987):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test (col1, col2) VALUES (?,?); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
$resource=sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $arrParams); 
sqlsrv_next_result($resource); 
sqlsrv_fetch($resource); 
echo sqlsrv_get_field($resource, 0);
```

Não utilizo SQL Server com PHP, então não posso comprovar sua eficácia, mas acredito que funcione corretamente, pois foi a resposta escolhida pelo autor da pergunta.